# Constraint across multiple columns based on row value

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I need help creating  constraints to prevent the following conditions in a SQL Server Database based on the table below.

1) If the owns flag is set for a given ID, a new row can not be added for that ID with the owns flag set.

2) An id can not be own by *different* ownerNames. (This is independent of the first case, say we allow the own flag to be set more then once for a ID). John cannot own ID 123 because David owns it, but we can have two records saying David owns ID 123.

```
Owns    Id           OwnerName
==============================
 1       123         David  
 1       123         John    
 0       123         Alexis  
 0       254         Brandon  
 1       956         Rod
```

Comment: Create Primary keys on id and name

Comment: @BHouse how would that solve this issue?

Comment: @SeanLange Op will get violation of primary key constraint error

Comment: This sounds a lot like a normalization problem. It seems like a separate table would be far more appropriate here.

Comment: It clearly is normalization problem, if primary keys are assigned properly, it shouldn't allow duplicates

Comment: @BHouse but that doesn't solve the problem. They want one and only 1 row for ID 123 to be allowed to be the owner. So following your key suggestion the posted data would be ok except that it violates the rule the OP is trying to solve.

Comment: This is just a bad design, the op should re-post the question with design questions,requirements and objectives. ID and Name constraints will not solve this issue, op stated 2 ppl can have the id, but not own it.

Comment: I agree with @SeanLange here, a separate table to specify who the owner is a far better idea than try to cope for both scenarios in one table.

Comment: There are details missing, can a `name` own an `id` is there a time increment, how do I know if someone already owns an ID, and if there is a duplicate record do you expect them to own the `id` for multiple instances of the record?

Comment: As a side note you could, however, create a filtered unique index on ID and Owns = 1.

Comment: that would not prevent the occurrence of multiple owners of an id in the table though

Comment: @Random_User , yes it would. Note I stated **UNIQUE**.

Comment: I stated that wrong, it would not allow the same owner multiple records in the database as the op stated was allowed.

Comment: Didn't notice that it states that someone can own something twice (which seems very odd...).

Comment: Yeah there is definitely some horrible design happening here but also the question is lacking a lot in the way of details of what the OP really wants. And sadly it seems the OP has disappeared. They posted a question and have not responded. Sad.

Comment: A solution for either of the numbers above will work. They don't have to work together. It seems the @Larnu filtered unique index may work. I need to research the implementation and give it a try. I posted  number two, in case I was unable to clean up the database properly  to eliminate duplicate rows(This has been simplified and figuring out which row to delete is complex )